# Print table columns next to each other so that they don't use the total table width if table has few columns

Tags: tables

I have a PDF file with table printed on two pages. The table can fit 9 columns (one column header and 8 data columns). The first page contains exactly 9 columns. The second page only has one column header and 3 data columns. The three data columns on the second page spread out the whole table width.

My question is how I can print the three data columns next to each other so that they can align the first three data columns on the first page?

Here is the MWE:

```
%!TEX TS-Program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,booktabs,fancyhdr}
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,makecell}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
%\usepackage{tabular}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\newcommand{\sectionheader}[1] {
\textbf{#1}

\rule{\textwidth}{6pt}
}

\newcommand\zcolumn[1]{%
{\begin{tabular}{c}#1\end{tabular}\linebreak[0]}}

\setlength{\heavyrulewidth}{0.12em}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{Report Name: SomeOne}
\rhead{\thepage}
\cfoot{}

\begin{document}

    \sectionheader{Data}

    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l*{8}X}

    \textbf{Catagory1}

     & {6/25/16} & {6/26/16} & {6/27/16} & {6/28/16} & {6/29/16} & {6/30/16} & {7/1/16} & {7/2/16}\\
    \addlinespace
{SubCatagory1}

     & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & -

    \\\addlinespace{SubCatagory1}

     & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & -

    \\\addlinespace
\hline

    \textbf{Catagory2}

     & {6/25/16} & {6/26/16} & {6/27/16} & {6/28/16} & {6/29/16} & {6/30/16} & {7/1/16} & {7/2/16}\\
    \addlinespace
{SubCatagory1}
     & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & -

    \\\addlinespace
\hline

    \textbf{Catagory3}

     & {6/25/16} & {6/26/16} & {6/27/16} & {6/28/16} & {6/29/16} & {6/30/16} & {7/1/16} & {7/2/16}\\
    \addlinespace
{SubCatagory1}

     & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & -

    \\\addlinespace{SubCatagory2}

     & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & -

    \\\addlinespace
\hline

    \textbf{Catagory4}

     & {6/25/16} & {6/26/16} & {6/27/16} & {6/28/16} & {6/29/16} & {6/30/16} & {7/1/16} & {7/2/16}\\
    \addlinespace
{SubCatagory1}

     & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & -

    \\\addlinespace{SubCatagory2}

     & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & -

    \\\addlinespace{SubCatagory3}

     & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & -

    \\\addlinespace{SubCatagory4}

     & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & -

    \\\addlinespace
\hline

    \textbf{Catagory5}

     & {6/25/16} & {6/26/16} & {6/27/16} & {6/28/16} & {6/29/16} & {6/30/16} & {7/1/16} & {7/2/16}\\
    \addlinespace
{SubCatagory1}

     & - & - & - & - & 1 & - & - & -

    \\\addlinespace{SubCatagory2}

     & - & - & - & - & - & 1 & - & -

    \\\addlinespace{SubCatagory3}

     & - & - & - & - & - & - & 1 & -

    \\\addlinespace{SubCatagory4}

     & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & 1

    \\\addlinespace
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\newpage

    \sectionheader{Data}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l*{3}X}

    \textbf{Catagory1}

     & {7/3/16} & {7/4/16} & {7/5/16}\\
    \addlinespace
{SubCatagory1}

     & - & - & -

    \\\addlinespace{SubCatagory2}

     & - & - & -

    \\\addlinespace
\hline

    \textbf{Catagory2}

     & {7/3/16} & {7/4/16} & {7/5/16}\\
    \addlinespace
{SubCatagory1}

     & - & - & -

    \\\addlinespace
\hline

    \textbf{Catagory3}

     & {7/3/16} & {7/4/16} & {7/5/16}\\
    \addlinespace
{SubCatagory1}

     & - & - & -

    \\\addlinespace{SubCatagory2}

     & - & - & -

    \\\addlinespace
\hline

    \textbf{Catagory4}

     & {7/3/16} & {7/4/16} & {7/5/16}\\
    \addlinespace
{SubCatagory1}

     & - & - & -

    \\\addlinespace{SubCatagory2}


     & - & - & -

    \\\addlinespace{SubCatagory3}

     & - & - & -

    \\\addlinespace{SubCatagory4}

     & - & - & -

    \\\addlinespace
\hline

    \textbf{Catagory5}

     & {7/3/16} & {7/4/16} & {7/5/16}\\
    \addlinespace
{SubCatagory1}

     & - & - & 1

    \\\addlinespace{SubCatagory2}

     & - & 1 & -

    \\\addlinespace{SubCatagory3}

     & 1 & - & -

    \\\addlinespace{SubCatagory4}

     & - & - & -

    \\\addlinespace
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\newpage



\bigskip

\newpage

\end{document}
```

Comment: do you want all columns on the same page?

Comment: @RunarTrollet,  I can't fit all columns on the same page. This is the only MWV, I only listed 11 dates. In the real application, I may have many date columns. In the last page, it's possible I only have few columns.

Comment: So you want every column to be the same width? You cannot use `tabularx` for that. You can calculate the necessary width, using fractions of `\textwidth` while subtracting for `tabcolsep` and some other lengths. Or just figure it out by trial and error: `\begin{tabular}{l*{8}{p{1.325cm}}}`

Answer (score 1):

I can see no urgent need for splitting the table into two parts. Remove some redundant information and consolidate all date strings in a single header row, and it's no problem at all to list all date columns in *one* tabular-like environment.

[image]

```
%!TEX TS-Program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,fancyhdr,tabularx}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\newcommand{\sectionheader}[1]{%
   \textbf{#1}\par
   \rule{\textwidth}{6pt}}

\newcommand\zcolumn[1]{%
   {\begin{tabular}{c}#1\end{tabular}\linebreak[0]}}

\setlength{\heavyrulewidth}{0.12em}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{Report Name: SomeOne}
\rhead{\thepage}
\cfoot{}

\begin{document}

\sectionheader{Data}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{} l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{11}c @{}}
\addlinespace
& \multicolumn{11}{c@{}}{Dates in late June and early July 2016}\\
\cmidrule{2-12}
& 6/25 & 6/26 & 6/27 & 6/28 & 6/29 & 6/30 & 7/1 & 7/2 & 7/3 & 7/4 & 7/5\\
\midrule   
\textbf{Category1}\\
    SubCategory1
    & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\ 
    SubCategory2
    & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\ 
\addlinespace
\textbf{Category2}\\   
    SubCategory1
     & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\ 
\addlinespace
\textbf{Category3}\\    
    SubCategory1
     & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\ 
    SubCategory2
     & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\ 
\addlinespace
\textbf{Category4}\\
    SubCategory1
     & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\ 
    SubCategory2
     & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\ 
    SubCategory3
     & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\ 
    SubCategory4
     & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\ 
\addlinespace
\textbf{Category5}\\
    SubCategory1
     & - & - & - & - & 1 & - & - & -  & - & - & 1 \\ 
    SubCategory2
     & - & - & - & - & - & 1 & - & -  & - & 1 & - \\ 
    SubCategory3
     & - & - & - & - & - & - & 1 & -  & 1 & - & - \\ 
    SubCategory4
     & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & 1  & - & - & - \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for the help! In real app, I may have many date columns which can't fit into one page. I do need to figure out how to print the last page with fewer columns but still align with other pages.

Comment: @y.h - Thanks. A general comment: it's really difficult [!] to provide specific information on issues that aren't revealed or explained.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I fixed it manually by adding extra "&" to each row in the second page. I was hoping to find some latex package to handle it, but I wasn't able to find it.